# Query for calling months as column and sum of values in month as rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2017

I have a table something similar to below.

```
Regions | Num | Date
USA       1     20/9/2021
USA       2     20/9/2021
USA       1     20/9/2021
USA       4     20/9/2021
USA       1     05/8/2021
USA       1     05/8/2021
USA       6     05/8/2021
```

What I want to achieve is the below

```
Name of KPI            | AUG 21 | SEP 21
Total number for month     8       8
```

I am currently using pivot to do the same but each time we add a new month I have to update my query. Trying to make it a bit more automated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Server dynamic PIVOT query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try with dynamic pivot. It's very easy to implement.
You can take help from below link.

[SQL Server dynamic PIVOT query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query)